# Unattended TFS Build Controller/Agent installation

Tags: build-agent

I´m scripting our build server dependencies and I'm having a little trouble getting the TFS 2010 build service configured unattended.

This is what I run from my script.

```
y:\Visual Studio Team Foundation Server 2010\TFS-x64\setup.exe /q /UnattendFile "y:\Visual Studio Team Foundation Server 2010\TFS-x64\TFS2010Build.ini"
```

and in the ini file I have the following:

```
<Configuration>
  <TeamBuild>
    <CollectionUri>
      <Uri>http://tfs2010.somedomain:8080/tfs/default</Uri>
    </CollectionUri>
    <Credentials>
      <FullName>somdomain\TFS2010BUILD</FullName>
      <Password>some password</Password>
    </Credentials>
    <Controller>
      <ControllerName>LocalController</ControllerName>
      <CustomAssemblyPath />
      <MaxConcurrentBuilds>0</MaxConcurrentBuilds>
    </Controller>
    <Agent>
      <AgentName>Agent1</AgentName>
      <ControllerName>LocalController</ControllerName>
      <BuildDirectory>$(SystemDrive)\Builds\$(BuildAgentId)\$(BuildDefinitionPath)</BuildDirectory>
    </Agent>
      <!--AgentName>Agent2</AgentName>
      <ControllerName>LocalController</ControllerName>
      <BuildDirectory>$(SystemDrive)\Builds\$(BuildAgentId)\$(BuildDefinitionPath)</BuildDirectory>
    </Agent>-->
    <Port>9191</Port>
    <UseSSL>False</UseSSL>
  </TeamBuild>
</Configuration>
```

I get TFS2010 Build service intalled, but not configured for some reason? When I start tfsmgmt.exe I'm presented with the wizard option.

[image]

Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is there any errors/warnings in the setup log?

Comment: No - TFS2010 get installed fine and it only installs the build service stuff. However it doesn't configure it for some reason.

Comment: Guess no one had the need to do an unattended installation...

Comment: Hey, sorry for the late reply. I haven't tried doing this before and I don't really know what is wrong. My best guest is that there was some failure along the way and didn't get properly logged. Have you looked into the "Logs" section to find if there is any log file? If this is still blocking your scenario, I'd recommend filing a Connect bug to Microsoft and we'll try a repro in house. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah - looked through the logs - came up empty. I'll file a bug. Thanks for the reply

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9572682/automating-team-foundation-build-configuration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The /Setup option has never been completed and has been left undocumented. There's no support for it and no guarantee that it will actually work... As you've found out.

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7719417/736079

As responded to a similar question, there is an option to do this using the API and building your own unattended configuration tool:

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9573948/736079