# Automating Team Foundation Build configuration

Tags: build-automation, tfsbuild

I am currently searching for a way to configure a Team Foundation Build service + one build agent without having to use the configuration wizard.

Is there a way to do this? Whether it be through command line (I haven't found any command line installation options for TFS Build), or through the API.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

To add to Pantelif:

And there is a 3rd option, also unsupported: [use the undocumented "/setup" commandline switch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7636995/tfs-2010-command-line-tfsconfig-setup-install).

And there is a 4th option, officially supported but still in beta: Use Team Foundation Server 11, which supposedly supports unattended installations out-of-the-box

Answer (score 2):

It should be possible to do this with a C# implementation.
E. Hofman has bloged about this [here](http://www.ewaldhofman.nl/post/2010/11/25/Programmatically-use-a-server-as-the-Build-Server-for-multiple-Project-Collections.aspx), see also [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jimlamb/archive/2010/04/13/configuring-multiple-tfs-build-services-on-one-machine.aspx) article by J.Lamb.
The context in both occasions is **not** supported by Microsoft - so any actions may void your quarantee.
Unless you really need to do something like described in those articles (multiple build services on one Server, build multiple collections with one build server, or something in that genre) I fail to see the point in proceeding with this instead of using the wizard.